# PyGIS remove QgsVertexMarker from scene

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, vertices, gui

I am writing a plugin that includes interaction with the map. Therefore, I use a `QgsMapTool`. It is possible for a user to mark a point on the map. When the user clicks a red X is drawn on the mapCanvas via `QgsVertexMarker`.

```
vertex_marker = QgsVertexMarker(self.canvas)
vertex_marker.setCenter(QgsPoint(map_coordinates['x'], map_coordinates['y']))
vertex_marker.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
vertex_marker.setIconSize(7)
vertex_marker.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_X)  # ICON_BOX, ICON_CROSS, ICON_X
vertex_marker.setPenWidth(2)
```

This is working fine. And the red X's are displayed on the map. But I can't delete the VertexMarker. I am trying to delete the VertexMarker from the scene. I've used something like this:

```
vertex_items = [ i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items() if issubclass(type(i), qgis.gui.QgsVertexMarker)]
    
for ver in vertex_items:
    if ver in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
        iface.mapCanvas().scene().items().remove(ver)
    
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Like this I get the used VertexMarker that are visible on the scene. But the remove function somehow doesn't remove the marker from the scene.

Is there another possibility to remove the `QgsVertexMarker` from the scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. 
Instead of

```
iface.mapCanvas().scene().items().remove(ver)
```

the item has to be deleted directly from the scene:

```
vertex_items = [ i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items() if issubclass(type(i), qgis.gui.QgsVertexMarker)]

for ver in vertex_items:
    if ver in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
        iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(ver)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a standalone application (without an interface) [Wien 2.8.1] use:

```
canvas.scene().removeItem(vertexMarker)
```

Found in [PyQgis Developer Cookbook/ Rubberbands and vertex markers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#rubber-bands-and-vertex-markers)

Comment: works also with QGIS 3

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a simple plugin that allows to zoom to a specific coordinates and draw a mark with an annotation pop up (image below) :

[image]

**1st :** You have to declare a global List that will contain the markers drawn in the scene:

```
Markers = []
```

**2nd :** Function to delete Marker Point:

```
def Delete_Marker(canvas):
   canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
   global Markers
   for mark in Markers:
      canvas.scene().removeItem(mark)
   canvas.refresh()
```

**3rd :** Draw New marker to the scene:

```
def Draw_Marker(canvas):
   canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
   # clear the canvas from previous added marker
   Delete_Marker(canvas)
   m = QgsVertexMarker(canvas)
   m.setCenter(pt)
   m.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
   m.setIconSize(10)
   m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_X)
   m.setPenWidth(3)
   # Add the drawn marker to the List of markers   
   Markers.append(m)
```