# Change QGIS Snapping-Utility-Vertex-Marker

Tags: pyqgis, snapping, gui

I am trying to change the appearance of the QGIS-Vertexmarker that is used when snapping is active and vertex/segment is found where you can snap to.

[image]

I think i found the code snippet where in the cpp files the appearance of this vertexmarker is set:

```
void QgsMapToolCapture::cadCanvasMoveEvent( QgsMapMouseEvent * e )
{
  QgsMapToolAdvancedDigitizing::cadCanvasMoveEvent( e );
  bool snapped = e->isSnapped();
  QgsPoint point = e->mapPoint();

  if ( !snapped )
  {
    delete mSnappingMarker;
    mSnappingMarker = nullptr;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !mSnappingMarker )
    {
      mSnappingMarker = new QgsVertexMarker( mCanvas );
      mSnappingMarker->setIconType( QgsVertexMarker::ICON_CROSS );
      mSnappingMarker->setColor( Qt::magenta );
      mSnappingMarker->setPenWidth( 3 );
    }
    mSnappingMarker->setCenter( point );
  }
```

(https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/bb9e276d591594821e2368f6ca077850baf1220b/src/gui/qgsmaptoolcapture.cpp)

In the PyQGIS-API I haven't found an entry for the QgsMapToolCapture so I have no idea how to change the Snapping Marker using PyQGIS.

Any idea how I can change the color, size and marker-style for the SnappingMarker?

Comment: I don't test it but I think you can just use QgsVertexMarker class https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVertexMarker.html and QCursor class to set cursor type http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcursor.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the snapping marker is different from the cursor.

Comment: Maybe look at this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172601/pygis-remove-qgisvertexmarker-from-scene

Comment: Defining the VertexMarker is not the problem but knowing where to define that this custum VertexMarker should be used for the Snapping Utility